# Female aviators

Tags: general-aviation

I have a friend who is convinced that there are some jets that can't be flown by woman. The argument was that the pressure created by the speed and altitude could burst the uterus... This sounds a great deal dramatic and when I researched it I couldn't find anything about it. But then again, I couldn't find a lot about female aviatiors as a whole.. But since I keep hearing this, I just can't get it off my mind.. Do anyone have any comments about this? Thanks in advance:))

Comment: This is complete nonsense. For what it's worth, we have female fighter pilots. Female pilots in the civil sector is even more common.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to  Aviation.SE.  Sorry, but this one is total nonsense.  Everything from the smallest aircraft to the Space Shuttle is flown by women. Voting to  close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question and the proposition it presents is nonsense.

Comment: Speed doesn't create force on body, acceleration does, and acceleration in airliners has nothing special as passengers can testify. On the other hand there are famous [aerobatics female pilots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wx_ui2qWgqI), and as @Simon mentions famous [Shuttle female Commanders too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eileen_Collins).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PeterKämpf Skeptics only deals with notable claims. "I read in the newspaper that X" is fine, but "My pal told me X" isn't sufficient for a Skeptics question. Also, even if the question was on-topic somewhere else, that wouldn't be a reason to close it here.

Comment: This is the sort of nonsense that people said 150 years ago to make women ride side-saddle on horses and keep them off bicycles. It's complete nonsense. None of these things will "burst her uterus" any more than they'll burst her (or a man's) bladder, stomach, intestines or anything else.

Comment: I wonder how your "friend" felt about female astronauts.  Maybe a browse through [Wendy Lawrence](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/lawrence.html)'s *c.v.* would be useful.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Actually, back in the day, NASA actually studied [what would happen if a woman had a period in space.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YNMkmydj1IA) Gotta love the 50's

Comment: @TomMcW Given that some of the early NASA scientists preferred working with monkeys, I am not surprised by a variety of their proposals and research questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolute nonsense. There are female F16 pilots who can pull 9g with all of their body fully intact, while you and I would suffer from a blackout.

To even publicly launch such a statement without any scientific backup is a disgrace.